# POST-request sent as GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I use jquery 3.4.1 and I am sending a post-request:

```
$.post({
    url: 'https://xyz.api.here.com/hub/spaces/mySpaceID/spatial', 
    success: x => { ... }, 
    data: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [52.4990273,13.3881283],
        apiKey: 'myAPIKey',
        accessToken: 'do I need this?'
    }
});
```

However when I see the request within devtools, there´s a GET-request instead of POST.

I found this similar post: https://blog.arvixe.com/why-is-jquery-ajax-sending-a-get-instead-of-a-post. The suggested workaround here is to append `/` at the end of the url. However that does not work for me, the request is still sent as GET.

So this is my code:

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<body>
  <script>
    $.post({
      url: 'https://xyz.api.here.com/hub/spaces/mySpaceID/spatial', 
      success: x => { ... }, 
      data: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [52.4990273,13.3881283],
        apiKey: 'myAPIKey',
        accessToken: 'do I need this?'
      }
    });
  <script>
</body>
```

Is this maybe any CORS-thing? My code runs on localhost, however I perform the request to the forementioned url.

Comment: on your server, a redirect  could transform a post to request...

Comment: @frenchy So I have no way if I do not own the server? Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: have a code return? you could try  to remove the domain, maybe the server completes it..

Comment: @Frenchy I get HTTP 400, probably because the resource can handle only POST. Remove the domain? eeeehm, which specifically you refer to? There´s not much in the above code I can omit, IMHO

Comment: Syntax of your `$.post` doesn't make sense and order of data and complete function is backwards

Comment: You can try `jQuery.ajax()`  instead with type: "POST".

Comment: @SinaRiani as of the [docs for `post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):  "This is a shorthand Ajax function". However I tried that already without success.